# SL4A client Python server

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, sl4a

## Summary

I want a Bluetooth connection between an Android Phone as client and Python as server. Please help me I can't figure it out. Server side must be on PC with Python. I need Python code as server and Sl4A can connect to this PC. I tried a lot of code but didn't get it to work.

## SL4A Bluetooth_chat.py

```
 import android   
 import time
 droid = android.Android()
 droid.toggleBluetoothState(True)
 droid.dialogCreateAlert('Be a server?')
 droid.dialogSetPositiveButtonText('Yes') 
 droid.dialogSetNegativeButtonText('No')
 droid.dialogShow() 
 result = droid.dialogGetResponse()
 is_server = result.result['which'] == 'positive'
   if is_server:
  droid.bluetoothMakeDiscoverable()
  droid.bluetoothAccept()
 else:
  droid.bluetoothConnect()

 if is_server:
    result = droid.dialogGetInput('Chat', 'Enter a message').result
    if result is None:
    droid.exit()
  droid.bluetoothWrite(result + '\n')

while True:
   result = droid.dialogGetInput('Chat', 'Enter a message').result
   if result is None:
   break
  droid.bluetoothWrite(result + '\n')

 droid.exit()
```

## MY ANSWER

```
import requests
from bluetooth import *

server_sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

port = server_sock.getsockname()[1]

uuid = "94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"

advertise_service( server_sock, "SampleServer",
               service_id = uuid,
               service_classes = [ uuid, SERIAL_PORT_CLASS ],
               profiles = [ SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ],
#                   protocols = [ OBEX_UUID ]
                )

 print("Waiting for connection on RFCOMM channel %d" % port)

client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()
print("Accepted connection from ", client_info)

try:
    while True:
        data = client_sock.recv(1024)
        if len(data) == 0: break
        print("received [%s]" % data)
             params=userdata)

except IOError:
    pass

print("disconnected")

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
print("all done")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using SL4A and ACTS that Google released:

**SL4A location:** `aosp_root/external/sl4a`

**ACTS Test Framework Location:** `aosp_root/tools/test/connectivity`

Within the test framework there is a testcase that can give you a start on BT

**testing over SPP:** `aosp_root/tools/test/connectivity/tests/google/bt/SppTest.py`